# Meta description missing on Google since migration from WordPress to Ghost

Tags: seo, google-search, blog, meta-description, ghost-blog

I recently migrated my WordPress blog to Ghost, an alternative to WP, powerful and fast.

I wrote this topic on the official Ghost forum:

https://forum.ghost.org/t/meta-description-is-missing-from-all-posts-pages/11554?u=pirmax

This concerns the lack of a description when I type the name of my site in Google.
In the source code of the home page, there is a meta description, OG / Twitter tags.
In the source code of the articles, there is no meta description, but the OG / Twitter tags are present.

It seemed to me that Google was able to read the content of the article to generate a description ... The articles are referenced but without description ...

[image]

I am wrong ?

Blog link (if you want to watch for yourself): https://www.yubigeek.com/

Comment: Where are you located?  I remember something recently about Google not being able to show snippets from sites in some specific countries without getting explicit permission first.

Comment: Hello, the website is french, and I'm in France.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. In France, for website of press, Google remove description of results.

To improve this, add this meta in page source code:

```
<meta name="robots" content="max-snippet:-1, max-image-preview:large, max-video-preview:-1">
```